# how to find $\frac{a}{b}$ given that $2a^2 + 2007a + 3 = 0$ and $3b^2 + 2007b + 2 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Given that
$$\begin{cases}
2a^2 + 2007a + 3 = 0 \\ 
3b^2 + 2007b + 2 = 0
\end{cases}
$$
and $ab \ne 1$, how to solve for $\frac{a}{b}$?

My try:
\begin{align}
2007a = -3 - 2a^2 \\
2007b = -2 - 3b^2 \\
\frac{a}{b} = \frac{-3 - 2a^2}{-2 - 3b^2}
\end{align}
Also,
\begin{align}
2a^2 = -2007a - 3 \\
3b^2 = -2007b - 2 \\
\frac{a^2}{b^2} = \frac{-2007a - 3}{-2007b - 2}\frac{3}{2} \\
\frac{a}{b} = \pm\sqrt{\frac{-6021a - 9}{-4014b - 4}}
\end{align}
Well, it doesn't look very promising. So I want to seek help here. How to find $\frac{a}{b}$ without actually solving for the roots? Hints are welcomed.

Comment: I upvoted: very nice effort.  However : **dead wrong approach.**  If an elegant approach does not present itself after a few minutes of contemplation, and if an inelegant (i.e. baby steps) approach is **obvious**, use it.  In this case, your are given separate quadratic equations in $a$ and $b$, so the **inelegant** (baby step) approach is to explicitly solve each quadratic.  Questions??

Comment: @user2661923 Yeah, but solving each quadratic makes the problem quite uninteresting. So I would rather go for some slightly more creative way when I know that an elegant solution exists

Comment: Good point, but inconclusive.  First of all, the problem might very plausibly have been a trap, where no elegance is possible, and the intention is to see if you get sidetracked.  Secondly, assuming elegance does exist, and absent mathSE, you can use your baby steps to solve the problem, and **then** try to reverse-engineer elegance, based on the baby-stepped solution.  Also, it is not uncommon that an elegance only approach (absent mathSE) might take 40 hours, while a baby-step and then elegance approach might take 1 hour.  For me, baby steps are the most powerful math weapon in my arsenal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathcal{Hint}$

Consider $2x^2+2007x+3=0$

Note that $a$ is one the roots.
Now, replacing $x$ by $\frac{1}{x}$

How does that affect the equation and its roots?

Comment: Thank you! got it

Comment: Very  nice hint!!